# How can ı retrieve data from sqlite and foreign key

Tags: java, android, sqlite, foreign-keys, android-sqlite

I have been stuck on foreign key problem , as normally I can retrieve data but I can't retrieve data with foreign key.

DB.Helper

```
 public static final String TBL_NAME="users";
    public static final String COL_ID="id";
    public static final String COL_NAME="name";
    public static final String COL_PASS="password";
    public static final String COL_EMAIL="email";
    public static final String COL_PIC="picture";


 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tasks";
    public static final String C_ID = "_id";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
    public static final String DETAIL = "description";
    public static final String TIME = "time";
    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_TODO_USER_ID_FK = "userId";



    public static final
    String TBL_QUERY="create table "+TBL_NAME+"("+COL_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COL_NAME+" text,"+COL_PASS+" text,"+COL_EMAIL+" text,"+COL_PIC+" blob)";



    public static final String Task_Query = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "
            + C_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + TITLE + " text, "
            + DETAIL + " text, "
            + TYPE + " text, "
            + TIME + " text, "
            +  KEY_TODO_USER_ID_FK + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TBL_NAME + ","
            + DATE + " text)";
```

ViewActivity

```
Cursor cursor = sb.rawQuery("select * from " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + " where " + Constants.C_ID + "=" + id, null);
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
TextView detail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
TextView notetype = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.note_type_ans);
TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alertvalue);
TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datevalue);
if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE)));
        detail.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.DETAIL)));
        notetype.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.TYPE)));
        time.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.TIME)));
        date.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATE)));

    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

So please help me how can I view only users task not all users tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to only retrieve data for a specific user, you need to include that in your query.  So, this:

```
Cursor cursor = sb.rawQuery("select * from " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + " where " + Constants.C_ID + "=" + id, null);
```

Should look something like this:

```
Cursor cursor = sb.rawQuery("select * from " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + " where " + Constants.C_ID + "=" + id + " and " + Constants.KEY_TODO_USER_ID_FK + "=" + userid, null);
```

But I don't know where you get the value for the 'userid' variable.

Answer (score 0):

The column `Constants.C_ID` which is `_id` is the auto increment integer primary key of the table `Constants.TABLE_NAME` (`tasks`).
Your query uses it to return 1 row that corresponds to the `id` that you use as a parameter here:

```
Cursor cursor = sb.rawQuery("select * from " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + " where " + Constants.C_ID + "=" + id, null);
```

If you want to return a user's task by using the user's id then you should do it like this:

```
Cursor cursor = sb.rawQuery("select * from " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + " where " + KEY_TODO_USER_ID_FK  + "=" + userId, null);
```

or even better:

```
Cursor cursor = sb.rawQuery("select * from " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + " where " + KEY_TODO_USER_ID_FK  + "= ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(userId)});
```

where `userId` is the id of the user that you want the results.
This query will return 1 or more rows for that `userId`.

Comment: but ı dont know how can ı make put extra userId variable